# Find the absolute max and min values of a multivariable function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization

Find the absolute minimum and maximum values of  $f(x,y,z)=x+2y+3z$ on the set $D=\left\{ (x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 | 1-z\ge \sqrt{x^2+y^2}, z\ge 0\right\}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x,y,z)=x+2y+3z$ can be thought of as a sequence of parallel planes.

$1-z\ge \sqrt {x^2 + y^2}$ is a cone.

The maximum of $f$ will either be at the vertex of the cone $(0,0,1)$

or it will be at the rim of the cone.

To evaluate the rim, set z = 0.

and we are looking for the line $f = x + 2y,$ that is tangent to the unit circle.

That point of tangency is $(\frac {1}{\sqrt 5} , \frac {2}{\sqrt 5}, 0)$

There are only two possible points to consider, which one maximizes $f.$